# CloudKit private database developer access

Tags: cloudkit

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to access a user's private database on the Development schema as the app developer. I'm just testing locally on my devices, but I need to be able to inspect the records of devices not associated with my developer account for debugging purposes.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to sign in to the [CloudKit Dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/) with that user's Apple ID. Their data is otherwise private.

Alternatively, you could create a mechanism in your app that pushes a user's data to the `Public` database of your app for help/troubleshooting purposes. That data is visible to you there as the app developer and you could download and inspect it.

Comment: Do you think such a mechanism is compliant with Apple privacy rules?

Comment: As long as you divulge what you are doing in the data sharing profile of your app in the App Store, it's probably fine.